# Newbie needing help with debounce errors in arduino

Tags: library, debounce

So I found a code I would like to use and not sure how to edit the code properly.

```
#include <Debounce.h>

void matrix(char matrix[7]) {
  int map[10];
  map[0] = 2;
  map[1] = 3;
  map[2] = 4;
  map[3] = 5;
  map[4] = 6;
  map[5] = 7;
  map[6] = 8;
  map[7] = 9;  

  int i=0;
  for(i=0;i<=7; i++) {
   if(matrix[i] == 0x30) { // 0x31=1, 0x30=0
      Serial.println(map[i]);
      digitalWrite(map[i],LOW);
   }
   else digitalWrite(map[i],HIGH);
  }
}

void show(int number) {
  switch(number) {
    case 0:
      matrix("11111100");
      break;
    case 1:
      matrix("01100000");
      break;
    case 2:
      matrix("11011010");
      break;
    case 3:
      matrix("11110010");
      break;
    case 4:
      matrix("01100110");
      break;
    case 5:
      matrix("10110110");
      break;
    case 6:
      matrix("10111110");
      break;
    case 7:
      matrix("11100000");
      break;
    case 8:
      matrix("11111110");
      break;
    case 9:
      matrix("11110110");
      break;
    default:
      matrix("00000010");
      break;
  }
}

#define t1 13
#define t2 12

Debounce debouncert1 = Debounce( 20 , t1 ); 
Debounce debouncert2 = Debounce( 20 , t2 ); 

void setup()   {
  Serial.begin(9600); 

  // initialize the digital pin as an output:
  pinMode(13, INPUT);
  pinMode(12, INPUT);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
}

int setCountPlus(int count){
  if(count == 9){
    count = 1;
  }
  else{
    count++;
    count %= 10;
  }
  return count;
}

int setCountMinus(int count){
  if(count==1){
    count = 9;
  }
  else{
  count--;
  count %= 10;
  }
  return count;
}

void loop()
{
  int i=-1;
  show(i);
  while(1){
    debouncert1.update();
    debouncert2.update();
    if(debouncert1.read()){
      i=setCountPlus(i);
    }
    if(debouncert2.read()){
      i=setCountMinus(i);
    }
    if(i==10){
      i=1;
    }
    show(i);
    delay(250);
  }
}
```

as for the errors.

sketch 65: error: 'Debounce' does not name a type 
sketch 66: error: 'Debounce' does not name a type 
sketch .ino: In function 'void loop()': 
sketch 108: error: 'debouncert1' was not declared in this scope 
sketch 109: error: 'debouncert2' was not declared in this scope

Any help would be great on fixing the code to stop getting errors.

Comment: Where did you believe that `Debounce` was supposed to be found?

Comment: You need to install the Decounce library first.

Answer (score 1):

In the description of [Debounce](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Debounce), you'll find the hint that this library is **outdated** and no longer maintained.

Its successors, **Bounce1** and, more recently, **Bounce2** are available from a **github** repository by Thomas Fredericks, [Bounce-Arduino-Wiring](https://github.com/thomasfredericks/Bounce-Arduino-Wiring).

Instead of simply downloading and unzipping the archive to `${HOME}/sketchbook/libraries`, you might want to consider that this is the right moment to get familiar with git repositories as an easily updatable source for third-party libraries.

Supposed that you're on a GNU/Linux system with `git` installed, you would

```
cd /${HOME}/sketchbook/libraries
git clone https://github.com/thomasfredericks/Bounce-Arduino-Wiring.git
```

to obtain a clone of the necessary data.

If the name of the directory of the library contains dashes (`-`), you'll have to change this name: remove the dashes or replace them with underscores (`_`). Names with dashes aren't valid!

Once in a while, you would change to the directory of the respective library and simply run `git pull` to update your local copy to the latest version of the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the switch type:
-SPDT (SIngle Pole Double Throw) - You would use a Cross Coupled NAND Gates (Flip Flop, Set Reset) This will set true to the side it sees power at from the switch and if it bounces it can't change state until the switch touch the other contact.

-SPST (Single Pole Single Throw) - You can use a software debounce where you would detect a signal and then wait for 10ms then read again and if there is a signal still, it is a debounced signal.  --OR--  You can use capacitors to help extend the life of a signal.

so debounce code

```
bool sw13=false;
bool sw12=false;
while(1){
if(digitalRead(13)==HIGH && !sw13){
  delay(20); //Delay For 20ms
  if(digitalRead(13)==HIGH){
    i=setCountPlus(i);
    sw13=true;
  }
}else{
    sw13=false;
}
if(digitalRead(12)==HIGH && !sw12){
  delay(20); 
  if(digitalRead(12)==HIGH){
    i=setCountMinus(i);
    sw12=true;
  }
}else{
    sw12=false;
}
if(i==10){
  i=1;
}
//show(i);
delay(250);
}
```